# Is that possible to add a tool tip in a bread crumb?

Tags: yii

> I want to implement some tooltip for breadcrumbs is there a way to do it.

Comment: Got the soloution through simple jquery command added it in the itemoptions of the breadcrumbs array.                                                               'rel'=>'tooltip','title'=>'click here to read the mail')),

Comment: make that an answer, when you can, and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the soloution through simple jQuery command added it in the itemoptions of the breadcrumbs array.

```
'rel'=>'tooltip','title'=>'click here to read the mail')), $this->menu=array(

array('label'=>'Inbox', 'url'=>array('MessageTo/inbox'),'itemOptions'=>array('class'=>'inbox', 'rel'=>'tooltip','title'=>'click here to read the mail')),


);
?>
```